# video source url issue in flowplayer

Tags: javascript, php, html, flowplayer

Using latest flowplayer have issue with making the video play.
Instead of regular link like this

```
<source type="video/mp4" src="http://mydomain.com/path/to/intro.mp4">
```

I have a dynamic link which has parameters for for further file determination

```
<source type="video/mp4" src="http://mydomain.com/stream.php?key=123">
```

which will return a video mp4 file after checking the key. When I try to use such link flow player return error : "html5: Unsupported video"

Please help with such problem, thank you

Comment: What headers does your script send to the client? Specifically `Content-Type`?

Comment: I believe @datasage is correct, you would need to something like `header('Content-type: video/mp4');` (not sure if thats the correct mime-type off the top of my head.

Comment: @PhilCross `video/mp4` would be correct.

Comment: headers look ok, at least content-type is there:

Comment: Content-Length:28191006
Content-Type:video/mp4

Comment: Make sure your script returning the video data is returning nothing else – especially no whitespace that might be outside of `<?php … ?>` tags … and of course no error message/warnings …